# Zooming to point boundary using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm wondering what the best strategy to position a map that has two points, using OpenLayers is. At the moment, my approach is to calculate the mid-point of the two points, and to zoom the map to that mid-point using the following approach:

```
var centerPoint = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);      
map.setCenter(centerPoint, zoomLevel);
```

However, this is not ideal as I don't know what the `zoomLevel` should be, so sometimes although the map is centered, the points are not visible.

Is there a better approach to dynamically position the map?

Answer (score 3):

the best way is that:

```js
map.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent());
```

---

```js
var firstExtent = firstLayer.getDataExtent();
var secondExtent = secondLayer.getDataExtent();

var totalBounds = firstExtent.extend(secondExtent);

map.zoomToExtent(totalBounds);
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of handling data on two separate layers? I have the two points style differently (I could also try to have them on the same layer but with separate styles I suppose).

Comment: i think you can extend your first bounds (first layer) with second bounds (second layer). i have updated my answer.

Comment: This does make sense, but strangely `firstExtent.extend(secondExtent)` is `undefined` (both `firstExtent` and `secondExtent` have bounds that exist).